# Can a Swift initializer have a variadic parameter?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, variadic-functions

Can a Swift init have a variadic parameter at the end so you can send multiple values of that type to the init?

An example would be to create a class that has an array of UIViews.  Would the following work?  Is it considered "legit" to do this?  (I know I could just pass an array of views, just wondering if this is an option.)

```
class viewsContainer {
  var myViews: [UIView] = []

  init(views: UIView...) {
    for view in views {
        myViews.append(view)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just did and it "seems" legit.  Pretty new to variadic parameters and trying to make sure I understand them before using them in a large project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a valid approach, but you should set different frames to not overlap the subviews.

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly legal. I just think it's best to pass an array of views instead (so `myViews` can be a constant), though. You could create a temporary array with the variadic parameter, and assign it to a private constant, but you, know...

Comment: `myViews` can still be a constant, replace the declaration with `let myViews: [UIView]` and the for loop with `myViews = views`

Comment: Passing a variadic is exactly the same as passing an array as the trailing parameter as far as the callee is concerned, it only changes the caller.  The only disadvantage of using the variadic approach is that the caller can't pass in an array of views, perhaps originating somewhere else.